# FFMPEG Conversion Fails

Tags: linux, centos, conversion, ffmpeg, media

Bad file?

I'm using FFMPEG so how can I better debug and trace these issues?

```
 ffmpeg -i /home/videospace/public_html/labo/lion.3gp new_video.flv
ffmpeg version N-57647-g1880294 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 30 2013 19:25:44 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-ffplay --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --extra-cflags=-fPIC --arch=x86_64
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/videospace/public_html/labo/lion.3gp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp6
    minor_version   : 256
    compatible_brands: isom3gp6
    creation_time   : 2013-04-11 07:48:16
  Duration: 00:02:43.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 206 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 194 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-11 07:48:16
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 31 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-11 07:48:17
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Output #0, flv, to 'new_video.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp6
    minor_version   : 256
    compatible_brands: isom3gp6
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-11 07:48:16
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-11 07:48:17
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> flv)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg4 @ 0x2659cc0] Error at MB: 1864337kB time=00:02:18.83 bitrate= 255.9kbits/s
[mpeg4 @ 0x2659cc0] concealing 263 DC, 263 AC, 263 MV errors in P frame
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2563900] stream 0, offset 0x40b8fc: partial file
/home/videospace/public_html/labo/lion.3gp: Invalid data found when processing input
frame= 4345 fps=1045 q=4.2 Lsize=    4503kB time=00:02:24.83 bitrate= 254.7kbits/s
video:3783kB audio:565kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.558660%
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the message looks like the file is corrupt or incomplete.

> [mpeg4 @ 0x2659cc0] Error at MB: 1864337kB time=00:02:18.83 bitrate= 255.9kbits/s
>   [mpeg4 @ 0x2659cc0] concealing 263 DC, 263 AC, 263 MV errors in P frame
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2563900] stream 0, offset 0x40b8fc: partial file

I would try downloading or re-sourcing it again.